# IOException: Permission denied when closing file stream

Tags: java, linux, exception, ioexception, permission-denied

On remote machine I've observed exception that I cannot reproduce or explain.

The same process have been running without issues for years. Multiple similar files are being downloaded from SCP to the shared network location on RedHat Linux, there is for sure free space on the disk and all permissions are fine. There are just a few file descriptors open. Today, out of sudden, while writing the last file there was `java.io.IOException: Permission denied` while **closing** the stream, but file was saved correctly.

**What are the possible causes of such exception?** I haven't found anything in the Java source code besides mapping of `Permission denied` to `EACCES`. While browsing the internet I only found cases when people were getting `Permission denied` while opening stream, but not closing it.

```
java.io.IOException: Permission denied
  at java.io.FileOutputStream.close0(Native Method)
  at java.io.FileOutputStream.access$000(FileOutputStream.java:53)
  at java.io.FileOutputStream$1.close(FileOutputStream.java:356)
  at java.io.FileDescriptor.closeAll(FileDescriptor.java:212)
  at java.io.FileOutputStream.close(FileOutputStream.java:354)
  at java.io.FilterOutputStream.close(FilterOutputStream.java:159)
  at com.aestasit.ssh.dsl.ScpMethods.doGet(ScpMethods.groovy:249)
  at com.aestasit.ssh.dsl.ScpMethods.this$2$doGet(ScpMethods.groovy)
  at com.aestasit.ssh.dsl.ScpMethods.download(ScpMethods.groovy:162)
  at com.aestasit.ssh.dsl.SshDslEngine.executeSession(SshDslEngine.groovy:70)
  at com.aestasit.ssh.dsl.SshDslEngine$remoteSession.call(Unknown Source)
  at com.aestasit.ssh.DefaultSsh.remoteSession(DefaultSsh.groovy:46)
  at com.aestasit.ssh.DefaultSsh$remoteSession.callStatic(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: it looks like internal linux problem (issue), cause Permission denied is quite strict exception. I mean it is not an error, it is normal behaviour. Who is running process, for whom do files belong and what about umask?

Comment: @DmitriGudkov if anything is wrong with file permissions, ownership or umask then I'm getting the same exception but when opening the stream, not closing it. Also trying to download and save the same file again couple of minutes later worked flawlessly. So I'm trying to understand what internal issue with Linux could have caused intermittent `EACCES` that isn't reproducible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just a theory ....

Looking at the Linux kernel source code, it seems that under some circumstances a `close(fd)` syscall will attempt to do an internal flush before closing.  If an `fd` was associated with a file on a "file system" where it was possible to change effective access permissions while a file was open, then it is conceivable that close's flush could fail because the *current* permissions are too restrictive.  That would turn into an EACCES syscall failure.

Such a failure would be rare because it is unusual for the permission of a file to change at just the "right" time to trigger the failure; i.e. between the `close` syscall and the previous `write` syscalls.

Furthermore, it is conceivable that this would only happen for certain kinds of files; e.g. files on a remote file server, where the remote server implements the access control.

---

Note that `close()` failing with EACCES is not envisage by the Linux manual entry or the POSIX specs.  The documents imply that access is only checked when a file is opened, this is (at least) is unexpected behavior.

However, the flipside is that various aspects of (virtual) file system behavior is dependent on the implementation of the file systems themselves.   And there are a few cases where file systems don't behave "normally".

Comment: What do you mean by "access control"? Are you aware of any mechanisms that manipulate with file permissions for a very short period of time?

Comment: I mean enforcement of file modes, ACLs, etcetera.  A `chmod` or `fchmod` syscall could happen in a very short time window

Comment: OK, probably you meant this kind of ACL on NFS: https://www.tecmint.com/secure-files-using-acls-in-linux/ Would this be a bug in this mechanism or rather expected behaviour that it could manipulate with permissions even if file is still being written?

Comment: In at least some cases it would be expected behavior.

Comment: And ACLs are not exclusive to NFS.  On a modern Linux file system they will work on local files as well.